# Selenium doesn't get all HTML in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to scrape data from a web page who needs me to be authenticated. I've managed to authenticate successfully using Selenium, but when I access the target page, while the information displays correctly in Chromium with no another click or whatever, my code only prints a part of the page's header and I don't understand why, I've already tried a lot of things like the explicit wait of the id I want, but the  result is a timeout. There is my code, thanks for your help.

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import sys




driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.boursedirect.fr/fr/login')

identifiant = driver.find_element(By.ID,'bd_auth_login_type_login')
mot_de_passe = driver.find_element(By.ID,'bd_auth_login_type_password')

identifiant.send_keys('XXXXXXXXXX')
mot_de_passe.send_keys('XXXXXXXXXXXX')

mot_de_passe.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(20)
driver.get('https://www.boursedirect.fr/fr/page/portefeuille')
time.sleep(5)
for _ in range(100):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "tabPTR")) )
print(driver.page_source)
```

I've already tried to:

- Scroll the page with `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`
- Execute the js :`driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")`
- Change my UA

Comment: Because the legality of web scraping varies across the world, the server might leverage techniques to prevent abusive scraping from clients. It seems not related to selenium, but to the server.

Comment: so how can i do ? do you have some ideas ?

Comment: what do you get in `driver.page_source`? Maybe it use `<iframe>` (and you have to `switch_to.frame`) or maybe it use `shadow DOM` to generate content.

Comment: Thanks for your help !! it was the iframe that prevented me from having the whole page